# Problem with Tailwind CSS when using the react-markdown component

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, react-markdown

The markdown is not working except for italic and bold. I have figured out that the problem is caused by Tailwind CSS because of how it handles text-size and other styles. If I comment out the `index.css` import (which defines the directives for Tailwind) in my `index.jsx`, all markdown types like heading, code, etc. work fine.

**News.jsx**

```
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import { useState } from 'react';

function News() {
  const [markdown, setMarkdown] = useState('# I am heading');
  
  return (
    <div>
      <textarea value={markdown} onChange={e => setMarkdown(e.target.value)} />
      <ReactMarkdown>{markdown}</ReactMarkdown>
    </div>
  );
}

export default News;
```

`index.css`

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import './index.css'
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
    <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: here is a link
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#headings-are-unstyled

Comment: you could also import the react-markdown styles in the tailwind.css...

Comment: @DenisTsoi how?

Comment: check the answer below - this might help (i.e. `prose` isn't included in Reactmarkdown

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should add typography plugin in your tailwindcss

1.install `npm install -D @tailwindcss/typography`

2.add the plugin to your `tailwind.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    // ...
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    // ...
  ],
}
```

3. use prose

```
<div class="prose lg:prose-xl">
  {{ markdown }}
</div>
```

Comment: indeed it work, but any explanation or links would be nice to understand deeply.

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin

Answer (score 4):

For any other viewers, i actually had to both...

1. install `@tailwindcss/typography` as eric suggested.
2. set `<ReactMarkdown className="prose"># Heading 1</ReactMarkdown>` as denis suggested.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks for clear and simple instructions.

Answer (score 3):

Ah I think i know what the issue is @ayex.

Your React markdown doesn't have the `prose` classname which is what tailwind uses for the default rendering of tailwind components/text

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-tailwind-markdown-forked-6thlhz?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A38%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A30%2C%22startColumn%22%3A33%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A30%7D%5D)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";

const defaultMd = `# iam heading`;

const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const [markdownSource, setMarkdownSource] = useState(defaultMd);

  const onChange = ({ currentTarget: { value } }) => {
    setMarkdownSource(value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <textarea
        onChange={onChange}
        value={markdownSource}
        className="
          font-mono
          overflow-auto
          whitespace-pre
          border-solid
          border
          border-gray-300
          resize
          w-full
        "
      />
      <ReactMarkdown className="prose">{markdownSource}</ReactMarkdown>
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <ExampleComponent />
  </div>
);

export default App;
```